# Как обрезать строку в python

Tags: python, строки

Мне нужно обрезать строку USDRUB до USDRUB. Никак не смог понять как это сделать. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Фильтруем буквы, значки(флаги) отбрасываем:

```py
res = ''.join(filter(str.isalpha, text))
```

Answer (score 1):

вам нужно оставить только большие буквы?

```
text = "USDRUB"

res = ''.join(l for l in text if l.isupper())

print(res)
```

Comment: Там не мелкие буквы, там спецсимволы )  Но ваш ответ всё-равно работает